# ng-list length validation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-nglist

I need validation for ng-list, means should restrict the user to enter more than three array list like `['121','565','435']` and if user tries to enter like `['121','565','435','787']` should give error like only 3 `vin` can enter.

Also if the user enter `['**1214**','565','435']` like above it should tell only 3 digits are allowed.

This is my input field:

```
<input type="text"  name="vin" id="vin" class="form-control"
 ng-model="vm.user.vin" ng-list required max-length="3"/>
```

I am new in AngularJS.

Comment: Oh .. it's very urgent? Well, let me clear everything off my plate to write code for you. Show us what you've got first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is asking to write code for him

Comment: @sirrocco ... Cool.  he gave enough details to us. also `I am new in angular js`, that's why he asked to write code from SO's. :) ...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/BQzp18gi7gksWG8OlXp0?p=preview here I am getting the validation for minlength and maxlenth.. means if you enter 1212,erere,erere,erere,erer in the input box it will give maxlength exceeded error.. same way minlength as well.. I needs to restrict  1212 to 121..that i am not able to do

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3YhEjKc2v48Eu0GRYmxX?p=preview

Comment: thanks Ramesh.. it is working fine.. and closing the ticket

Comment: @kiran  Don't forget to click accept my answer and put up vote , it may helps to others and me :p

Comment: hi Ramesh... where is that option to click accept my ans...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the default validate properties for ng-list, but you can customise the validation like

```
<input type="text" name="vin" id="vin" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="vm.user.vin" ng-list required max="3" ng-change="isBigEnough(vm.user.vin)" />

                    <span ng-show="vm.user.vin.length > 3">array length should below than three</span>
                    <span ng-show="IsElementLength">element length should below than three</span>
```

and your controller side code

```
$scope.isBigEnough = function (values) {
        if (values != undefined) {
            values.every(function (element, index, array) {
                if (element.length > 3) {
                    $scope.IsElementLength = true;
                    return false;
                }
                $scope.IsElementLength = false;
                return true;
            })
        }

    }
```

Result

> - ['121','565','435'] - No error message
> - ['1211','565','435'] -element length should below than three
> - ['121','565','435','543']- array length should below than three
> - ['1211','565','435','543']- array length should below than three and element length should below than three

i have bring the code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3YhEjKc2v48Eu0GRYmxX?p=preview), but i did't test it on plunker.

Comment: here if i submit the form it is hitting the server even if there is error IsElementLength